# INHERITS postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute this statement in my "postgresql" database.

```
CREATE TABLE hotel_h999.formula_contadores  INHERITS (public.formula_contadores) WITH (oids = false);
```

I want the hotel_h999.formula_contadores table to have the same fields as public.formula_contadores.

Someone could validate if it is well structured. There is something wrong but I am unable to see it.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «INHERITS»
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE hotel_h999.formula_contadores  INHERITS (public...` well is in Spanish but is sintax error near "INHERITS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO

You need to add parentheses after the create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE hotel_h999.formula_contadores() INHERITS (public.formula_contadores) WITH (oids = false);
```

But do you really want to use inheritance or are you just wanting to create the same table structure?  If the latter, then you would be better off generating the create script from your existing table and changing the name.

Comment: The intention is to inherit from public.formula_contadores to add constraints to the new table.
All of the database follows this structure, I have no choice.